# Notes and slides combined with psnup from powerdot output in 16:9 ratio

Tags: powerdot

I am using powerdot to produce slides and notes in the 16:9 ratio. I would like to combine each slide and the corresponding note in one page for handouts.

This can be done when the powerdot option `paper=a4paper` is used by using psnup. Here is a simple minimal example of the powerdot

```
\documentclass[%
    style=simple,
    display=slidesnotes,
    mode=print,
%    paper = 169, 
    paper=a4paper,
]{powerdot}
\usepackage{blindtext}  
\begin{document}

\begin{slide}[toc=,bm=]{Introduction}
\blindtext
\end{slide}

%-----------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{note}{Notes}
\blindtext
\end{note}
\end{document}
```

This generates a PostScript file with two A4 pages in landscape orientation. I can combine them using psnup as follows

```
psnup -pa4 -f -2 test.ps test2.ps
```

My problem is that this psnup command does not work when I choose the powerdot `paper=169` option. The slide text is clipped in both width and height. I have played around with psnup options -w -h etc., instead of -pA4, but can't find a solution.

Comment: `psnup -pA4 -2 -f -H371mm test-utf8.ps test2.ps` seems to work for me, but don't ask me what psnup is thinking.

Comment: No such luck at my end. I presume the utf8 part of the file name is insignificant? I'm not sure how to show a screenshot here. What I get is the slides one on top of each other (as required), but a bounding box (in landscape orientation) is superimposed. This box aligns with the bottom left of the new page and clips it.

Comment: Now, if I go into the test2.ps file and edit it to exchange the coordinates of the upper right of the bounding box, and if I tell GSView to 'rotate media', then I do get the full slide and notes pages. 

However, it's not good, because there is a lot of empty vertical space. This will be because the aspect ratio of the 19:6 slides is unfriendly to the manoeuvre. When you put two A4 landscape pages on top of each other you get A3, with the same aspect ratio as A4 (in portrait).